# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to plot ellipses for Gaussian mixture according to this implementation:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

def draw_ellipse(position, covariance, ax=None, **kwargs):
    """Draw an ellipse with a given position and covariance"""
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    
    # Convert covariance to principal axes
    if covariance.shape == (2, 2):
        U, s, Vt = np.linalg.svd(covariance)
        angle = np.degrees(np.arctan2(U[1, 0], U[0, 0]))
        width, height = 2 * np.sqrt(s)
    else:
        angle = 0
        width, height = 2 * np.sqrt(covariance)
    
    # Draw the Ellipse
    for nsig in range(1, 4):
        ax.add_patch(Ellipse(position, nsig * width, nsig * height,
                             angle, **kwargs))
        
def plot_gmm(gmm, X, label=True, ax=None):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    labels = gmm.fit(X).predict(X)
    if label:
        ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=labels, s=40, cmap='viridis', zorder=2)
    else:
        ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], s=40, zorder=2)
    ax.axis('equal')
    
    w_factor = 0.2 / gmm.weights_.max()
    for pos, covar, w in zip(gmm.means_,gmm.covariances_, gmm.weights_):
        draw_ellipse(pos, covar, alpha=w * w_factor)
```

On calling function:

```
plot_gmm(gmm,cust)
```

I get the following error in this line:

```
width, height = 2 * np.sqrt(covariance)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Shape of gmm.covariances_ is (4,3,3)

Comment: The error says that `covariance` (actually its `sqrt`) has more than 2 elements.  That's the `covar` in the calling function (you can read the code, can't you?), which comes from iterating on `gmm.covers_`.  If that array is (4,3,3), then `covar` is (3,3).  You can check that by adding a `print(covariance.shape)` statement before the error line.

Comment: Yes I know, why am I getting an extra dimension when Im not supposed to ..is my doubt.. the columns in cust array is also 2 as on the refernce of this implementation I took